# optimize Octave code for Zhang Suen thinning algorithm

Tags: vectorization, octave

I would like to know if it is possible to vectorize ([cf page 599 of this doc](https://docs.octave.org/octave-5.1.0.pdf)) operations that need a whole matrix scan, but with a lot of conditions to check concerning neighbours pixels. The goal is to make it faster, because the code is working when I use a for loop with 10 iterations, but I tried using a while loop, and it never ends. It might also be me screwing the stop condition, but I think the operations could still be faster. The operations I want to optimize are described [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm).
Here is the code that I want to optimize:

```
    while (stopCond>0)
      
      stopCond = 0;
      
      ap1 = 0;
      bp1 = 0;
      tabPixel = [];
      for x=2:NL-1
          for y= 2:NC-1
            p1 = imgSeuil(x,y);  %current pixel
            p2 = imgSeuil(x-1, y); %pixel neighbours
            p3 = imgSeuil(x-1, y+1);
            p4 = imgSeuil(x, y+1);
            p5 = imgSeuil(x+1, y+1);
            p6 = imgSeuil(x+1, y);
            p7 = imgSeuil(x+1, y-1);
            p8 = imgSeuil(x, y-1);
            p9 = imgSeuil(x-1, y-1);
            
            tabNeighbour = [p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9];
            tmpTabl = diff([tabNeighbour, p2]);
            tmpTabl = max(tmpTabl, 0);
            
            ap1 = sum(tmpTabl);
            bp1 = sum(tabNeighbour);
    %%%--------Can I vectorize ops with below conditions--------
            if((p1==1)&&(bp1>=2)&&(bp1<=6)&&(ap1==1)&&
              ((p2==0)||(p4==0)||(p6==0))&&
              ((p4==0)||(p6==0)||(p8==0)))
%%%adding indexes of current pxl matching these conditions to then change their value when loop is over
                tabPixel = [tabPixel, [x; y]];
                stopCond += 1;
              endif
          endfor
      endfor
    
      for i=2:columns(tabPixel)
        imgSeuil(tabPixel(1, i), tabPixel(2, i)) = 0;
      endfor
```

I also read that using bolean indexing is encouraged, and I would like to know if those changes would significantly improve exec time.

Here is the whole code if you want to run it :

```
clear all;
close all;

img=imread("/home/redouane/Documents/L3/S6/TIA/TD/ED_3_6_originale.png");
imshow(img);
colorbar();

sizeImg = size(img);
NL=sizeImg(1,1);
NC=sizeImg(1,2);

tab=zeros(2,256); %tab de niveaux de gris
tab(1,1:256)=0:255;

%remplissage tab niveaux de gris
%et affichage de l'histogramme
for y=1:NL
    for x= 1:NC
        val=img(y,x);
        tab(2,val+1)=tab(2,val+1)+1;
    end
end

ticktab=zeros(1,25);

for i=1:25
    ticktab(1, i)=10*i;
end

figure(2);
plot(tab(1, 1:256),tab(2, 1:256));
set(gca,'XTick',ticktab(1, 1:25));
xlim([0, 255]);
%seuillage de l'img
figure(3);
imgSeuil=img;
for y=1:NL
    for x= 1:NC
        val=imgSeuil(y,x);
        if(val<30)
            imgSeuil(y,x)=0;
        else
            imgSeuil(y,x)=255;
        end
    end
end
imgSeuil=~imgSeuil;%inversion pour lignes blanches
imshow(imgSeuil);

%squelettisation: cf Zhang Suen algorithm sur rosetta code
%%%--------------

stopCond = 1;

while (stopCond>0)
  
  stopCond = 0;
  
  ap1 = 0;
  bp1 = 0;
  tabPixel = [];
  for x=2:NL-1
      for y= 2:NC-1
        p1 = imgSeuil(x,y);  %les voisins du pixel
        p2 = imgSeuil(x-1, y);
        p3 = imgSeuil(x-1, y+1);
        p4 = imgSeuil(x, y+1);
        p5 = imgSeuil(x+1, y+1);
        p6 = imgSeuil(x+1, y);
        p7 = imgSeuil(x+1, y-1);
        p8 = imgSeuil(x, y-1);
        p9 = imgSeuil(x-1, y-1);
        
        tabNeighbour = [p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9];
        tmpTabl = diff([tabNeighbour, p2]);
        tmpTabl = max(tmpTabl, 0);
        
        ap1 = sum(tmpTabl);
        bp1 = sum(tabNeighbour);

        if((p1==1)&&(bp1>=2)&&(bp1<=6)&&(ap1==1)&&
          ((p2==0)||(p4==0)||(p6==0))&&
          ((p4==0)||(p6==0)||(p8==0)))
            tabPixel = [tabPixel, [x; y]];
            stopCond += 1;
          endif
      endfor
  endfor

  for i=2:columns(tabPixel)
    imgSeuil(tabPixel(1, i), tabPixel(2, i)) = 0;
  endfor

  ap1 = 0;
  bp1 = 0;
  tabPixel = [];

  for x=2:NL-1
      for y= 2:NC-1
        p1 = imgSeuil(x,y);
        p2 = imgSeuil(x-1, y);
        p3 = imgSeuil(x-1, y+1);
        p4 = imgSeuil(x, y+1);
        p5 = imgSeuil(x+1, y+1);
        p6 = imgSeuil(x+1, y);
        p7 = imgSeuil(x+1, y-1);
        p8 = imgSeuil(x, y-1);
        p9 = imgSeuil(x-1, y-1);
        tabNeighbour = [p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9];
        ap1 = sum(diff([tabNeighbour, p2]));
        bp1=sum(tabNeighbour);
          if((p1==1)&&(bp1>=2)&&(bp1<=6)&&(ap1==1)&&
          ((p2==0)||(p4==0)||(p8==0))&&
          ((p2==0)||(p6==0)||(p8==0)))
            tabPixel=[tabPixel, x; y];
            stopCond += 1;
          endif
      endfor
  endfor

  for i=1:columns(tabPixel)
    imgSeuil(tabPixel(1, i), tabPixel(2, i))=0;
  endfor
endwhile


figure(4);
imshow(imgSeuil);

%%%-------------

##tabSquel=zeros(1,10);
##hold on;
##for y=2:NL-1
##        for x= 2:NC-1
##            % on utilise ces valeurs pour ne pas acceder aux bords de l'image
##            %Pixel1 (P1) correspond à imgSeuil(y,x), c'est le pixel du milieu et on etudie ses voisins
##            A=0;%nombre de transi de 0 à 1
##            B=0;%nombre de voisins
##            
##            tabSquel(1,2)=imgSeuil(y,x);%p1
##            tabSquel(1,2)=imgSeuil(y-1,x);%p2
##            tabSquel(1,3)=imgSeuil(y-1,x+1);%p3
##            tabSquel(1,4)=imgSeuil(y,x+1);%p4
##            tabSquel(1,5)=imgSeuil(y+1,x+1);%p5
##            tabSquel(1,6)=imgSeuil(y+1,x);%p6
##            tabSquel(1,7)=imgSeuil(y+1,x-1);%p7
##            tabSquel(1,8)=imgSeuil(y,x-1);%p8
##            tabSquel(1,9)=imgSeuil(y-1,x-1);%p9
##            tabSquel(1,10)=imgSeuil(y-1,x);
##
##
##sum = (0.5*(abs(tabSquel(1,6)-tabSquel(1,1)) + abs(tabSquel(1,7)-tabSquel(1,6)) + abs(tabSquel(1,8)-tabSquel(1,7)) + abs(tabSquel(1,9)-tabSquel(1,8)) + abs(tabSquel(1,2)-tabSquel(1,9)) + abs(tabSquel(1,3)-tabSquel(1,2)) + abs(tabSquel(1,4)-tabSquel(1,3)) + abs(tabSquel(1,5)-tabSquel(1,4))));
##          if(sum==3)
##              plot(y,x, "ro-");
##          end
##    end
##end
%imshow(imgSeuil);
```

[image]

Comment: As to your second question: that should be easy to verify. Implement and then time it. Also, to prevent a `while` loop from going infinite I always include a `maxIter` as maximum number of iterations. If that's exceeded, the loop ends.

Comment: stenciled image operations should generally be vectorizable, but I do want to point out that you're going to have some performance penalties based on how you're building your output variable. in general it is a bad idea to initialize a matlab/octave array as empty and then continually append results to it in a loop. this requires growing the variable, which can be a very inefficient and expensive process as the array grows. Matlab has implemented some runtime optimizations to to reduce the penalty, but octave has not. better to pre-allocate `tabPixel` with known size and assign values to it.

Comment: Most of those operations can be performed by `filter2()`, e.g. "At least one of P2 and P4 and P6 is white" translates to `filter2([0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 1 0], img) < 3`. `A(P1)` is a bit trickier but could be done with a look-up table and encoding each of the 8 positions as a power of 2 in the filter kernel, e.g. `H = [128 1 2; 64 0 4; 32 16 8]`.

Comment: So far I have measured a 0.6seconds improvement per iteration just by allocating memory to tabPixel instead of continuously appending to it. I'm going to try the ideas highlighted by @beaker next. I will post my results as an answer if they are satisfying! Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Can you post a sample image? What were your original timings? Are you measuring a 0.6 second improvement over 1 second or 1000?

Comment: I measured a 0.6 seconds improvement per iteration going from 10.4 to 9.8 sec. With the image i'm working on, it takes 18 iterations before there is no more pixel changed. So, it takes approximately 3 minutes and I gained roughly 10sec in total just with the first adjustment. I added the image i'm working on. I won't be able to work much on this project right now but i'll post an answer when i'm done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try out the idea of generating a lookup table for each of the 256 possible neighbor combinations. Given a kernel:

```matlab
encoding_kernel =
     1   128    64
     2     0    32
     4     8    16
```

we can use [`filter2`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/filter2.html) to encode each neighborhood of 8 pixels to an integer in the range 0..255.

Now we just need to determine which bit combinations satisfy the conditions. You'll notice that P1 is multiplied by 0 in the kernel. We'll just use the thresholded image directly to get the value of P1. I've only coded the LUT for Step 1 in the algorithm, but Step 2 is virtually identical.

```
% generate Step 1 lookup table for encoded neighborhood of P1
%
% encoding_kernel
%    1   128    64
%    2     0    32
%    4     8    16
    
LUT_Step1 = ones(256, 1);

% generate binary values for keys 0..255
% pixel ordering is: [P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9]
binary_keys = dec2bin(0:255, 8)-'0';   % -'0' makes the array numeric

% LUT = LUT AND (2 <= B(P1) <= 6)
B_P1 = sum(binary_keys, 2);
LUT_Step1 = LUT_Step1 & (2 <= B_P1) & (B_P1 <= 6);

% Generate A(P1) by finding the transitions from 0 to 1
% which corresponds to a value of 1 in the diff
A_P1 = sum(diff([binary_keys, binary_keys(:,1)], [], 2) == 1, 2) == 1;
LUT_Step1 = LUT_Step1 & (A_P1 == 1);

% At least one of P2 and P4 and P6 is white (0)
LUT_Step1 = LUT_Step1 & ~all(binary_keys(:,[1,3,5]), 2);

% At least one of P4 and P6 and P8 is white (0)
LUT_Step1 = LUT_Step1 & ~all(binary_keys(:,[3,5,7]), 2);
```

I haven't manually verified all of the values in the LUT, but from a spot check it seems to be correct. On my machine, a 3GHz Core i5, generating the table took about 0.7-0.8 msec. You could, of course, hardcode the resulting table in your script if you wished.

---

Once you have the lookup table and the kernel, checking the conditions is pretty easy. Just encode the current image, and then look up the encoded value in the table and if it's 1, then the image should be 0 at that location. (We don't really need to make sure that the image is 1 (black) before applying the other conditions, because changing 0 to 0 doesn't change the outcome.)

```
clear all;
close all;

% generate the lookup table
zs_lookup_table;

img=imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejNSg.png");
imshow(img);
colorbar();

% threshold img
figure(2)
imgSeuil = img < 30;
imshow(imgSeuil);

encoding_kernel = [
   1   128    64
   2     0    32
   4     8    16
   ];


% use "valid" in filter2 to ensure each pixel has 8 neighbors
% valid region of image is 1 pixel smaller on each side,
% so we'll need to adjust when we recalculate imgSeuil
encoded_img = filter2(encoding_kernel, imgSeuil, "valid");
% use lookup table to determine which pixels satisfy conditions 1-4
conds1_4 = false(size(imgSeuil));
conds1_4(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = LUT_Step1(encoded_img+1);  % convert range to 1..256
imgSeuil(conds1_4) = 0;  % no need to explicitly check for pixel == 1

figure(3)
imshow(imgSeuil);
```

The timings for each pass through Step 1 varied a bit more then generating the table, probably because I updated the image between iterations and there were fewer pixels changing in later iterations. Each pass took between 0.7 and 1.7 msec. Again, I didn't code Step 2 and I didn't check for changes between iterations, but adding it all together you should be able to reach equilibrium in well under a second.

Comment: Nice job, I can't try it right now but it's impressive (for me at least) ! Thank you very much. Do you happen to know if octave would run this kind of programs faster on a computer with a GPU ? I only have an old laptop to run it, so I can't really test it.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't try to squeeze every bit of performance out of this since the first pass looks like it will reduce the time from around 10 sec per image to what will likely be less than 0.1 sec per image once all the pieces are in place. I'm not sure that any speedup from the GPU would be worth the overhead of transferring the images, but it's certainly worth a try.